# Function method in object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I am working on a Javascript object exercise. My output is not what I expected. Please take a look at my code and give some advise. Here is the code:

```
function myFunction(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.models = new Array();
  this.add = function (brand){ 
    this.models =  brand;
  };
}
var c = new myFunction ("pc");
c.add("HP");
c.add("DELL");
console.log(c.models);
```

The output is `"DELL"`

My expected output is `["HP","DELL"]`

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: a multiple argument version: `this.add=[].push.bind(this.models);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the add function. You want to push the brand into the model. Not set the model to it.

```
this.add = function (brand){ 
    this.models.push(brand);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To add something to an array, you should use the `.push()` method.

Change your code to:

```
function myFunction(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.models = new Array();
  this.add = function (brand){ 
    this.models.push(brand);
  };
}
```

P.S. It is customary to name such constructor type of functions starting with a capital letter.